# Populate custom group lookup field using PHP

Tags: custom-object, php

I am new to Salesforce (but experienced php developer).  My trouble is with populating a custom group lookup field via php.  The salesforce dashboard was setup by someone else; and I'm learning my way around.

I have an "Account" group with a "Name" data field.  Insertion works perfectly.

There is a custom group "Contact" which has a lookup field "Account" with data type "Lookup(Account)"; which is also a required field.

I am using the REST API PHP examples here:
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php

My issue is updating the contact lookup field.

Here is the section of PHP code where I am having the trouble:

```
$contact_data['Account'] = array( 'Name' => $insert_account_id);
.... more fields here...

$param = json_encode( $contact_data );

hnsfInsert('Contact', $param);
```

I'm pretty sure my issue is with the array I am passing for the "Account" field.  I am able to retrieve the account ID from the insertion of the main "Account" record (which works fine).

My problem is tying the "Contact" to the "Account" via the lookup field.

What are the array key, values for a custom group lookup field while using PHP?

Thank you ever so much for any assistance.

Comment: Are you using __c with field name?

Comment: Hello, so sorry for delay. I think I just made progress. It seems the "Account" field is required internally, but I can still create a record by ignoring the "Account" field. I kept trying to find the info to pass; I didn't think about just ignoring the "Account".  Ignoring it still allows the record to be created in the Contact group.  THANK YOU for your time!!  By the way... what do the "__c" and "__r" names stand for?

Comment: $contact_data['AccountId'] = $insert_account_id; did you try this ?

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it.  @karthikselva, the "Account" was required internally; but simply updating the FirstName and LastName pushed it into the required field.  No idea why it works this way.. but I'm learning.  Thank you for your time.